# Don't know meaning and reason of 'return type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)' in python metaclass example code

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm trying to understand about Python Metaclass. I almost understand what Metaclass do in python, but I can't understand meaning of example code

```
class MakeCalc(type):   
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):      
        namespace['desc'] = 'calculation'              
        namespace['add'] = lambda self, a, b: a + b    
        return type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
```

Why does this Metaclass return `type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)`? What does it mean?

Comment: `__new__` should return the object created by the class instantiation. If nothing special is needed, the default implementation `type.__new__` can be used to create it.

Comment: For future readers, it would help if you provided a link where you found the example code. Also, that code above isn't valid, it's not indented properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider what it means to define a class:

```
class Simple:
    pass

class NotAsSimple(Simple):
    pass
```

We're stating that `Simple` has a base class (just `object` in this case). It has a name. It will also have a `dict` for storing it's attributes called a namespace. `NotAsSimple` has an additional base class. Python essentially translates those lines above into arguments to pass into `type` which calls `type.__new__`. It is there where it's composed into a "new" object that is returned, in this case, a class. Those are part of the default steps for creating a class. All classes can be thought of as an instruction manual for building "things". A metaclass is just a fancy name for the instruction manual for building instruction manuals. Changing the metaclass is saying, use my instruction manual for building this instruction manual (and you can make it not return a new instruction manual if that's what you want).

```
class UsesMeta(metaclass=MakeCalc):
    pass
```

When `MakeCalc` is used as a metaclass, `MakeCalc.__new__` is used. Once it adds to the namespace, the regular call to `type.__new__` is made to finish the jobs that need to be done just like before.

As a side note, the example of `MakeCalc.__new__` provided doesn't actually do anything that couldn't be done with a regular class.